# Any other alternative to write this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select data base upon three conditions

1. Find the latest date (StorageDate Column) from the table for each record
2. See if there is more then one entry for date (StorageDate Column) found in first step for same ID (ID Column)
3. and then see if DuplicateID is = 2

So if table has following data:

```
ID   |StorageDate | DuplicateTypeID
1    |2014-10-22  | 1
1    |2014-10-22  | 2
1    |2014-10-18  | 1
2    |2014-10-12  | 1
3    |2014-10-11  | 1
4    |2014-09-02  | 1
4    |2014-09-02  | 2
```

Then I should get following results

```
ID  
1
4
```

I have written following query but it is really slow, I was wondering if anyone has better way to write it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TD.RecordID)
FROM dbo.MyTable TD
JOIN (
    SELECT T1.RecordID, T2.MaxDate,COUNT(*) AS RecordCount
    FROM MyTable T1 WITH (nolock) 
    JOIN (
    SELECT RecordID, MAX(StorageDate) AS MaxDate
            FROM MyTable WITH (nolock)
            GROUP BY RecordID)T2 
    ON T1.RecordID = T2.RecordID AND T1.StorageDate = T2.MaxDate
    GROUP BY T1.RecordID, T2.MaxDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )PT ON TD.RecordID = PT.RecordID AND TD.StorageDate = PT.MaxDate
    WHERE TD.DuplicateTypeID = 2
```

Comment: Would there be a situation where an ID is of duplicatetype 2 but *doesnt* show in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic function `rank` , can you try this query ?

```
Select recordId from
(
  select *, rank() over ( partition by recordId order by [StorageDate] desc) as rn 
  from mytable
) T
where rn =1
group by recordId
having count(*) >1
and sum( case when duplicatetypeid =2 then 1 else 0 end) >=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see how the performance goes:

```
;WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StorageDate DESC) AS StorageDateRank,
                    COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, StorageDate) AS StorageDateCount
        FROM        MyTable
    )

SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM tmp
WHERE StorageDateRank = 1   -- latest date for each ID
  AND StorageDateCount > 1  -- more than 1 entry for date
  AND DuplicateTypeID = 2   -- DuplicateTypeID = 2
```